# Error running MFP Analytics console using Development server

Tags: analytics, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

Getting these errors when clicking on the analytics icon from MFP Console

```
SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.translateJsp:570'
com.ibm.ws.jsp.JspCoreException: JSPG0049E: /console/header.jsp failed to compile : /Users/mourawi/Documents/devel/workspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/workarea/org.eclipse.osgi/64/data/temp/default_node/SMF_WebContainer/AnalyticsUI/analytics/console/_header.java : 1 : The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files 
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.translateJsp(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:570)
at [internal classes]
at com.ibm._jsp._index._jspService(_index.java:104)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:101)
at [internal classes]
```

Comment: MFP Studio 7.0 (Developer's Edition) - no full server installed on Mac

Comment: See my answer. Verify your setup is equivalent.

Comment: Try to navigate to the console using the URL and see if you get the same issue. localhost:10080/analytics/console.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot confirm the above.
Here is my setup:

Mac 0S X 10.10.3
Eclipse Luna SR2
IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.0.0.00-20150430-1556 (latest from the Eclipse marketplace)

- Created a new project application
- Started the server
- Opened the console
- Clicked the Analytics icon
- Entered admin/admin in the login screen
- Analytics console displayed

[image]